# RESTEASY002142 warnings when returning two different MIME types with JBoss

Tags: jboss, resteasy

I'm trying to upgrade a JBoss server from RESTEasy 3.0.10 to 3.1.0.  One  of our resources is allowed to return data in plain text or in XML.  It is working correctly, but producing warning messages "RESTEASY002142: Multiple resource methods match request".

The code basically looks like this:

```
@Path(value = "info")
public interface InfoResource {

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public InfoObject getInfo();

@GET
@Produces("text/xml")
public InfoObject getInfoXML();
}
```

The warning message happens every time the server receives a request for the "info" resource and does not specify a preferred return type with the "Accept" header.  Is there something wrong with this code?  Is there some way to get rid of the warming messages?

Note that the "Library" class example from JBoss in this [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.0.GA/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Content_Negotiation.html) produces the same error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can eliminate the warning message by placing both possible return types into the "Produces" annotation.

A `MessageBodyWriter` will convert the InfoObject into the desired format.

```
@Path(value = "info")
public interface InfoResource {

  @GET
  @Produces({"text/plain", "text/xml"})
  public InfoObject getInfo();
}
```